# How can I find the probability of a continous random variable given its mgf?

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, moment-generating-function

The following question is from my book:

> If the mgf of $X$ is

$M(t) = \dfrac {e^{5t} - e^{4t}}{t}, t \not = 0$, and $M(0)=1$,

find **(a)** $E(X)$, **(b)** Var$(X)$, and **(c)** $P(4.2 < X \le 4.7)$

I that to find the mean and the variance I just compute $M'(0)$ and $M''(0)-[M'(0)]^2$. But I'm not sure how to do part c. Am I supposed to guess the PDF $f(x)$, knowing that $\displaystyle \dfrac {e^{5t} - e^{4t}}{t} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx} f(x)dx?$

Comment: can you add the self-study tag?

Comment: This should not be a guess.  The question should provide enough information to derive the pdf. from the properties given for the mgf.

Comment: Here is a hint: the probability you are looking for is equal to 0.5. Can you tell why?

Comment: @JohnK Well I see that $4.7-4.2=.5$, and $5-4 = 1$, and $\dfrac {.5}{1} = .5$ So I'm guessing this is the mgf of a uniform distribution over the interval $(4, 5)$?

Comment: You can verify this.

Comment: @JohnK Okay. So I guess it's as I expected, the only elementary way to do it is to try to guess the PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally with textbook problems like this you can figure it out by looking at a table of MGFs. Try looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples) and see if that helps.

If that doesn't help, you can in principle recover the pdf from the MGF by noting the connection between MGFs and [Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). This is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353490/deducing-a-probability-distribution-from-its-moment-generating-function), for example. I can add more details if those links aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

From wikipedia on the Uniform distribution:
The moment-generating function is:[2]
$$
{\displaystyle M_{x}=E(e^{tx})={\frac {e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t(b-a)}}\,\!}
$$
In your case, b = 5 and a = 4. So the distribtuion is a uniform distribution from 4 to 5.

Comment: This is a `self-study` question, hence providing the entire solution does not help in understanding the principle behind the question.